# How to deal with python inheritance with methods that have same names and depend each other?

Tags: python

I try to maintain a class. The basic program struct I hoped shows below.

```
class FooFather():
    def __init__(self):
        self.meta=0
    def add(self):
        self.meta+=1
    def act(self):
        self.add()
class FooChild(FooFather):
    def __init__(self):
        FooFather.__init__(self)
    def add(self):
        self.meta+=2
    def act(self):
        FooFather.act(self)
```

The result shows below.

```
foo=FooChild()
foo.act()
print(foo.meta)
=>2     //not 1 I want to have
```

I understand the mechanism. The child class overwrites the methods of father (both add and act). How can I overwrite a method meanwhile I can keep the relation between original methods?

Comment: what is `foo.shot()`?

Comment: Why are you overriding `act` if all you do is call the superclass implementation?  Why not just not override it and let the superclass one be called automatically?

Comment: Sry. That is a miscopying. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: So you're trying to override a function, without rewriting the superclass, while keeping the same names?

Comment: @aensm exactly! Is it too ambitious?

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the current instance. So when `FooFather.act()` calls `self.add()` it is referring to the `add` method of the current instance, which is a `FooChild()` instance. Therefore `FooChild.add(self)` is called.

If you want `FooFather.act()` to call `FooFather.add()` instead, you need to have `FooFather.act()` do so explicitly: i.e., `FooFather.add(self)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want really based on your question, but I'm guessing something like this, where `act` calls the superclass' `add` (using python 2.7 syntax):

```
class FooFather(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.meta=0
    def add(self):
        self.meta+=1
    def act(self):
        self.add()
class FooChild(FooFather):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FooChild, self).__init__()
    def add(self):
        self.meta+=2
    def act(self):
        super(FooChild, self).add()
```

Comment: Ya. That is a solution. When the father class is big, it is not that perfect. If I want to keep the same API, I have to get my hands "dirty" I.E. I almost need to rewrite the methods. What I image is that I call father's method and the will call the method of its own instead of the current instance. Sry for my poor explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo privates, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

```
class FooFather:
    def __init__(self):
        self.meta = 0

    def __add(self):
        print self.meta, '-->',
        self.meta += 1
        print self.meta

    def act(self):
        self.__add()

class FooChild(FooFather):
    def __add(self):
        print self.meta, '==>',
        self.meta += 2
        print self.meta

    def act2(self):
        FooFather.act(self)

    def act3(self):
        self.__add()



>>> c = FooChild()
>>> c.act()
0 --> 1
>>> c.act2()
1 --> 2
>>> c.act3()
2 ==> 4
```